# ag-grid how to change the paging button text

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid for displaying grid view. It works fine.

Is it possible to change the paging button **next** and **previous** text with arrows? Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: It may provide helpful to your helpers with a link and maybe a code sample.

Comment: have you read through the documentation? https://ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-styling/index.php

Comment: Yes I gone through the ag-grid documentation but I can't find any samples regarding changing the pagination button text with icons.

Comment: looking through the documentation and the code on the paging elements for ag-Grid, it appears that the pagination controls are hard coded.  you would either need to modify the template in your local copy of the component, or request a feature change from the developers.  https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/blob/master/src/ts/rowControllers/paginationController.ts#L19

Comment: It appears that the template also uses the localization service: https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/blob/master/src/ts/rowControllers/paginationController.ts#L318.  You could create a custom localization and replace `[FIRST]`, `[PREVIOUS]`, etc, with your own values.  Ultimately, however, this seems like something for the developers to help you with.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the markup of these buttons:

[image]

You can get hold of these buttons by a selector and do whatever you want.

Let me replace the "Next" button with an image.

```
document.getElementById('btNext').innerHTML = '';

var image = document.createElement('<img>');
image.src = 'images/myarrow.jpg';
document.getElementById('btNext').appendChild(image);
```

This is a rough demonstration on how you could do it.